# Does OpenXava framework support Web Services?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, frameworks, openxava

I have an OpenXava application and I would like to expose a REST API allowing external users and even other applications to do HTTP POST requests to my OpenXava Entities, thus creating new resources in my database.

Does anyone know if OpenXava can generate web services for my entities? I am using OpenXava 5.2.1.

I already read the [documentation](http://openxava.wikispaces.com/index_en) but found nothing about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenXava does not generates web services for each entity automatically. However, an OpenXava application is a regular Java web application, so you can write the web services for your application in the usual way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @javierpaniza. Do you plan to have this web service generation feature in future OpenXava releases? I think it would be of greatful use. Most REST operations (HTTP GET, POST, PUT/PATCH, DELETE) can be used as CRUD operations. Anyway, I will implement it like in a common Java web application.

Comment: Yes, we have plans for an automatic web service generation for OpenXava, but not for the very next versions, though.